# Magento 2: Run setup:di:compile a Specific Module

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile

Is it possible to di compile to specific module instead of **whole magento** di compile ?

Because, Whole Magento take a long time to compile. So, is it possible to di compile to specific module.

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile CompanyName_ModuleName
```

Please help me. If it is possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this by follow this step :

Go to :

> /var/www/html/YourMagento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php

Find this line :

```
$modulePaths = $this->componentRegistrar->getPaths(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE);
```

Replace this below line and add path of the module which you want to compile like this :

```
$modulePaths = ['CompanyName_ModuleName' => '/var/www/html/YourMagento/app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName'];
```

Make sure module register with this`CompanyName_ModuleName` in `registration.php` file.

It's temporary solution for di compile single module. Remove di generated module folder and refresh cache.

Hope, It will helpful for you.

Comment: Happy to help !! Happy Coding :)

Comment: excellent work....Suggest to  create a custom command and implement the this logic

Comment: Yes, a custom command that could be integrated in `bin/magento` or `n98-magerun` would be great

Answer (score 2):

If your focus is to try to contain as well as possible the downtime of your production, the below may help:

You could clone your codebase on the same server and separate folder (clone basically).

Once both environments would coexist, you can deploy static content on the clone without penalising the production environment uptime.

Finally, when the deploy is complete, you could either symlink the pub/static folder or just rsync. Of course, this may be done with a script.